# Msg 8966, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Could not read and latch page (1:1681) with latch type SH. sysindexes failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Msg 8966, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not read and latch page (1:1681) with latch type SH. sysindexes failed.

What does this mean ?

is it that DB is currupted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your DB is corrupted, sorry.

Actions suggested by [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226390%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

> `HARDWARE FAILURE`
>
> Run hardware diagnostics and correct any problems. Also examine the Microsoft® Windows NT® system and application logs and the SQL Server™ error log to see if the error occurred as the result of hardware failure. Fix any hardware related problems.
>
> If you have persistent data corruption problems, try to swap out different hardware components to isolate the problem. Check to ensure that your system does not have write caching enabled on the disk controller. If you suspect this to be the problem, contact your hardware vendor.
>
> Finally, you might find it beneficial to switch to a completely new hardware system, including reformatting the disk drives and reinstalling the operating system.
>
> `RESTORE FROM BACKUP`
>
> If the problem is not hardware related and a known clean backup is available, restore the database from the backup.
>
> `DBCC CHECKDB`
>
> If no clean backup is available, execute `DBCC CHECKDB` without a repair clause to determine the extent of the corruption. `DBCC CHECKDB` will recommend a repair clause to use. Then, execute `DBCC CHECKDB` with the appropriate repair clause to repair the corruption.
>
> `Caution`: If you are unsure what effect `DBCC CHECKDB` with a repair clause has on your data, contact your primary support provider before executing this statement.
>
> There is no repair for this error, because it is only a symptom of the real problem. See the accompanying errors for details.

Comment: i did DBCC CHECKDB all but one gave

Msg 8966, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not read and latch page (1:1681) with latch type SH. sysindexes failed.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

i did DBCC CHECKDBand one of the DB gave

Msg 823, Level 24, State 2, Line 2
I/O error 21(The device is not ready.) detected during read at offset 0x0000000001c000 in file 'E:\MSSQL2000\Data\FTSWE_Data.MDF'.

Comment: Windows returned error `21` (`ERROR_NOT_READY`) while reading your file. This most probably means hard driver failure. Stop you database and see if you can copy `E:\MSSQL2000\Data\FTSWE_Data.MDF` manually.

Comment: the server was restarted and it worked well.how to find which file is currupted?

Comment: is working well for the time being is worse then the persistent problem...coz it pushes the problem under the carpet?

Comment: `@dan455`: make a backup (I mean it), replace your hard drive and restore from the backup. Hard drives are cheap these days, data loss is not. If you don't want to replace a hard drive, just make a backup then while you're still able.

Comment: I work on Mobile broadband/vpn ...
would that be the reason for the hrdware failure?


Further its my work system and so i will have to ask permission to do so.ok thnks 
there is a wuery that is getting locked